# Fixed Header CSS - Email Signup Form Only

Tags: html, css, fixed

I'm trying to make email signup form fixed at the top once user starts scrolling down - see image below.

I understand how to make fixed header, but I only want the form to be fixed.

Currently I wrap signup form in DIV with this style:

```
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 100px;
z-index: 101;
```

But it does not push the content down AND when I start scrolling, form is still 100px below top of VIEWPOINT ... what do I do

**NO FIXED HEADER CSS**
[image]

**WITH FIXED HEADER CSS**

Notice how form is 100px down - I want it to be all the way at the top of VIEWPOINT, after scroll

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have `top: 100px` in your CSS rule. Just change that with javascript after you scroll down.

Comment: @jperezov - how do I do that? I don't know JS or how to implement it... also - what if JS is disabled?

Comment: JS being disabled isn't a realistic issue. There's no way to do what you want purely in CSS. If you don't know JS, you're gonna have to spend some time learning it, as I won't be able to cover everything in a mere comment.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding correctly, you could achieve this by checking your current scroll position on the page using jquery.scroll.

Knowing this you could toggle a class on your form container that fixes it to top:0;

HTML

```
<div style="height:3000px;">
   <div id="form"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#form {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:150px;
    width:550px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:tomato;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.offset{top:100px !important;}
```

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var position = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (position > 100) {
      $('#form').addClass('offset');
    } else {
      $('#form').removeClass('offset');
    }
});
```

Here's how it would look like in a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/9wa25far/